# Is it possible to verb anything other than a noun?

Tags: verbs, verbing

Is it possible to verb anything other than a noun?

Although slightly meta, I noticed that English SE has verbing as a tag, rather than verbing-nouns.

Comment: I suspect there are some adjectives that can be made into a verb.  Can't think of any, though.

Comment: And what is the definition of "verb" as a verb?  Is it _to make a non-verb into a verb_?  Because if so, then this all gets really shady.

Comment: @advs89: Because it's an autological word?

Comment: Well, because if you make an non-verb into a verb, then it is now a verb.  So now it is no longer a non-verb...  which makes the whole thing fall apart (it's a logical contradiction).  My guess is that my original definition is faulty, but what _is_ the correct definition?

Comment: @advs89: No more difficult than alchemy. It used to be lead, now it's gold.

Comment: you're right - I'm not even sure what I was arguing earlier.  (I think I need some sleep)

Comment: But no buts! (Not from Shakespeare, but, according to Wikipedia, from Susanna Centlivre's play, The Busie Body.)

Comment: Sorry mistyped: "But me no buts."

Comment: In the accepted answer, if the verb is *weirds*, then it's applied to a noun (*language*). If the argument is that *verbing* is a verb, the thing it's applied to is not stated, so the case is still not made. The other answers also apply verbs to nouns, as far as I can see. Would you agree? ... Oh, scratch that. I thought you used *verbing* to mean *applying a verb to something* (like *plastering*), not *turning something into a verb* (like *cocooning*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can for example verb an adjective.

> Verbing weirds language.

Comment: I note that this is from Calvin and Hobbes (http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/calvin.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(linguistics)#Humor). Though for some reason I misremembered it as "verbing weirds nouns" -- anyone remember if that's been used in a comic strip somewhere?

Comment: I’m not quite convinced by this.  It’s a great quote, but I hear it as deliberately slightly pushing the boundaries of what sounds right — *verbing* comes quite naturally, *weirds* not so much.  I’d be much more convinced by a less meta example!

Comment: +1: sure it's not quite as natural as "trending" or "verbing," but I'd say it still counts.

Comment: @PLL 'weird' is a fairly common colloquial verb. E.g., the phrasal construction 'weird out' in "that weirds me out".

Answer (score 7):

*Garner's Modern American Usage* has a nice discussion of "Adjectives as Verbs" under the heading **Functional Variation. E.** Garner warns that these transformations often have a trendy or jargonistic quality but adds,

> There are exceptions (greening rooftops). And to copyeditors, it is natural to talk about *lowercasing* and *uppercasing* words.

Comment: Is this possibly a case of verbing an adjective that's been nouned?

Comment: I think the problem with "verbing" is that it depends on which came first.  It's not verbing if a word started out as a verb and was "adjectived (if you will)."  So then it becomes the case of the chicken and the egg.  Which came first:  "to uppercase (verb)" or "uppercase (adjective)?"

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: If I’m not mistaken, it’s actually verbing a noun that’s been adjectivised (I can’t bring myself to write *adjectived*), or even just directly verbing a good honest noun, since the roots of all these were the upper and lower cases in which the metal type was stored.

Answer (score 1):

Several adjectives for colors have been verbed.

In addition to the recent use of `greening` (in the environmental sense), there's the `yellowing` of paper. We also `brown` foods, such as ground beef. Interestingly, we `blacken` foods; we don't `black` them. And we `whiten` clothes and teeth. Rounding out the colors, people have `greying` hair.

Comment: I do not think that these examples are convincing without further proofs because color names are also used as nouns.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I can't seem to think of any color names used as a noun. (Other than `orange`, or `black` and `white` people, but those seem to be relevant here.) Can you provide some examples?

Comment: I cannot, either.  My point is that color names are not good examples of verbed adjectives.

Comment: Out of `the blue`, it hit me, while I was sitting on `the green`? :)

Comment: Some reds are redder than others, I've read.

Answer (score 1):

Came across an example of someone smugging for the camera today, which is a beautiful turn of phrase in multiple ways: the verbing of an adjective, plus the parallelism with mugging, which conveniently already means something similar (and was itself a result of verbing a noun).

Comment: I like it, and it answers the question by giving a very good example. However, someone might flag your contribution as not answering the question, or not providing support or references. The question was asked 6 years ago, and since then the site's expectations have risen.

Comment: So... would you mind posting a link to  that specific example, or providing a definition? Some of our users are not native speakers and they might struggle with its meaning. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, those of us who *are* native speakers would struggle with disentangling the derivation of *smugging.*