# What word means "to make something obsolete"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What word means *to make something obsolete*?

For example, the automobile made the horse and buggy obsolete. How would the word **obsolete** be applied as a verb?

**obsoleted**

> The automobile **obsoleted** the horse and buggy.

bleech.

**made obsolete**

> The automobile **made obsolete** the horse and buggy.

Not bad, but there's room for improvement.

EDIT: I'm looking for a verb that has an edge; that captures the upheaval and aggressiveness involved in displacing a product or industry. *Killed* is a bit strong.

**killed**

> The automobile **killed** the horse and buggy.

A bit overstated.

**ran out of business**

> The automobile **ran** the horse and buggy **out of business**

marginally better, but still not good.

**disrupted**

> the automobile **disrupted** the horse and buggy

Better applied to an industry, like so

> the automobile **disrupted** the transportation industry in the early 20th century; particularly the horse and buggy.

Wordy.

**smashed**

> The automobile **smashed** the horse and buggy.

More along the lines of what I seek, but a bit improper.

**XXX**

> The automobile **XXX** the horse and buggy.

What verb fits best here?

Comment: It looks like **obsolesce** can be either a transitive or intransitive verb, but seeing it in actual usage is rare.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolesce

Comment: You could just use *replaced*. Or *superseded*.

Comment: "The automobile *obsolesced* the horse and buggy?" Maybe *eclipsed*?

Comment: I would say "obsoleticify", but you probably won't find that in any dictionary.

Comment: 'Obviate' typically applies when the object of the verb is actually the *need* for a given thing, but previous suggestions likely apply better based on your example.

Comment: I would change the word order from "The automobile made obsolete the horse and buggy." to "The automobile made the horse and buggy obsolete."

Comment: The automobile made horse and buggy redundant.

Comment: Twenty answers posted so fat and not one accepted by the OP suggest that this question is either opinion based or too broad. It also hints that the OP is not overwhelmingly convinced by any of the solutions supplied,  they ought to explain why in their question (IMO).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I always wait a week before accepting an answer, to allow time for responses. Also, respectfully disagree on your point: this is a focused question, fact-based, and carefully aligned with site guidelines.

Comment: Well "always" probably doesn't refer to this site because this is your second question on EL&U. The first one was posted in 2017 and no answer was accepted :) You may not be aware but four users (with privileges)  consider your question to be off-topic, the question may or may not be closed but if it were watertight that risk would not have occurred.

Comment: @Mari-lou I have thousands of points on SO, and even if I didn’t, why resort to an *ad hominem* attack? Just because a question receives various answers does not make it opinion-based/broad. The best questions also generate discussion.

Comment: I'm not aware of attacking you. I am only suggesting why this question might be placed on hold, you can take my advice or leave it. Moreover, this is a Q&A site not a forum so discussions are discouraged outside of meta. But I am not attacking you, I don't know where you got this idea from.

Comment: QFT: *this is your second question on EL&U. The first one was posted in 2017 and no answer was accepted :) * <— here you attack my posting history.

Comment: @kmiklas , it's just "made obsolete".  It is utterly commonplace in English that there is NOT especially a particular form (verb, adverb, adjective etc) of a given word.  In that case you just use a word phrase, here "made obsolete".  It is completely commonplace in English that the answer to the type of question you have asked is just "there's no such form, you just say blah-blah phrase."

Comment: It seems you made an easily overlooked edit to make the point that you want an edgy word. Could you change your title to something like **Edgy word that means “to make something obsolete”?** Otherwise, I see why you would be waiting awhile to pick the best answer. As of now, none of them are "edgy".

Comment: As mentioned in HLuc's answer, the standard phrase with "obsolete" is "to render something obsolete".

Comment: "Video Superseded the Radio Star" doesn't really have the same ring to it.

Comment: For software engineers reading this question, to _void_ may be a good choice. As in to void a record, rendering it invalid.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Interestingly, you automatically used a word in your question that you didn't even comment on—perhaps without realizing what you'd done: [**displace**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/displace):

> **1 a** : to remove from the usual or proper place
>   *specifically* : to expel or force to flee from home or homeland
>   // *displaced* persons
>   **1 b** : to remove from an office, status, or job
>   **1 c** *obsolete* : to drive out : BANISH
>   **2 a** : to move physically out of position
>   // a floating object *displaces* water
>   **2 b** : to take the place of (as in a chemical reaction) : SUPPLANT

So, in your example sentence:

> The automobile *displaced* the horse and buggy.

Comment: The implication with "displaced" is that it wasn't made (completely) obsolete, just moved sideways. Which is the case with horses and buggies: business and everyday use went away, recreational use did not. The flat panel display did not merely displace the vacuum tube colour television, it replaced it (or obsoleted it).

Comment: Yes, this has that bit of assertiveness that I was looking for. Somewhere between “bumped” and “superseded”

Answer (score 81):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the verb *supersede* is close.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/supersede):

> **supersede** — to replace something older, less effective, or less important or official:
>   *Wireless broadband could supersede satellite radio one day.*

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersede)

> 1a : to cause to be set aside
>   1b : to force out of use as inferior.

Comment: "The automobile *superseded* the horse and buggy."

Comment: -1 The iPhone X supersedes the iPhone 8. But it did not make the iPhone 8 obsolete. What definition of obsolete do you think supersede applies to? (E.g., no longer in general use; fallen into disuse? of a discarded or outmoded type; out of date?)

Comment: @CanisLupus: Consider the first two definitions for supersede (1a and 1b) in [Merriam-Webster.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersede) *"To force out of use as inferior"* is a definition very close what the OP is looking for.

Comment: And even by the Cambridge dictionary definition I quoted above, the iPhone X has not superseded the iPhone 8, because it has not *replaced* it. If it did replace it, then the iPhone 8 would be out of production, and would, at least in one sense, be obsolete. What definition of [*replace*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/replace) are you using?

Comment: My mistake, Perter. I have upvoted!

Comment: The word *retire* can also be used in this way.

Comment: Supersede is quite wrong. Supersede just means to take the place of a thing previously in use; to supplant.  (Often because it's "better", but often with no connection at all to "better", it often just means "follows".)  That is wholly unrelated to making something obsolete.  Each new year's car model supersedes the previous year's car model, but this has no connection to obsolescence.  Indeed the definition "To force out of use as inferior" has no connection to the older thing being obsolete.  Telegraphs are obsolete, steam locomotives are obsolete, and so on.

Comment: Note that something, A, may *make obsolete* something else, B.  But in fact A does ***not*** replace (ie: supersede) B.   A just makes it obsolete.

Comment: @Fattie: Something that has been 
"forced out of use as inferior" is  **by definition** obsolete. [See Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obsolete): *obsolete: no longer used or needed, usually because something newer and better has replaced it*

Comment: ?  Yes, that's a fair definition of obsolete - "forced out of use", no longer usable.  Supersede just means "follows".

Comment: @Fattie: no it doesn't. You can't say **Monday always supersedes Sunday*. And in your last comment, you've just admitted that definition 1b in *Merriam-Webster* means *"make obsolete"*. The fact that *supersede* also has some other definitions doesn't change the fact that for the OP's sentence, definition 1b in *Merriam-Webster* fits what he wants very well.

Answer (score 57):

to **supplant**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/supplant)

> 1. To take the place of; to replace

As in:

"The automobile supplanted the horse and buggy."

Comment: @AledCymro because it wasn't the word he liked

Answer (score 50):

**Obsolete**

It's less commonly used as a verb than an adjective (my subjective opinion), but that's exactly what it means.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete

> obsolete
>
> verb
>
> ob·​so·​lete | \ ˌäb-sə-ˈlēt  , ˈäb-sə-ˌlēt\
>
> obsoleted; obsoleting
>
> Definition of obsolete (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> transitive verb
>
> : to make (something) old-fashioned or no longer useful : make obsolete

Comment: The Oxford English dictionary marks this as a US usage https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsolete -- but it's pretty commonly used in England these days and I'd call it a welcome import to our language.

Answer (score 44):

***Deprecate*** is a term often used with technology: e.g. a *deprecated* feature or framework.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deprecate):

> 1.1  **be deprecated** (chiefly of a software feature) be usable but regarded as obsolete and best avoided, typically because it has been superseded.
>   -  *‘this feature is deprecated and will be removed in later versions’*
>   -  *‘avoid the deprecated element that causes text to flash on and off’*

Comment: These examples are passive uses, and the original example is looking for an active verb with the replacement as subject. A sentence like "The automobile deprecated the horse and buggy" may get the meaning across, but sounds rather strange to me.  "The automobile caused the deprecation of the horse and buggy" seems better to me, but leaves the same issues "obsolete" had.

Comment: Also "deprecate" usually means *intentionally* making something as obsolete so that people stop using it.  (E.g., "this function is deprecated: please use function2 instead!")  So it's a somewhat more specific word.

Comment: This is just wrong. Why all the up-votes? To deprecate something means to tell people not to use it. The question is quite clear on the intended usage and this is not it.

Comment: @aschepler "The automobile deprecated the horse and buggy" is complete nonsense. It means "The automobile advised people not to use the horse and buggy."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I did have the feeling it was the wrong subject for the verb.

Answer (score 15):

Consider **[eclipse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclipse)**:

> to cause an eclipse of: such as
>   a : OBSCURE, DARKEN
>   b : to reduce in importance or repute
>   c : SURPASS

Surpass is relevant here. In essence, the automobile overshadows its earlier form. It's not that the horse and buggy is dead. It's that it has been effectively replaced as the dominant mode of travel.

> The automobile *eclipsed* the horse and buggy.

Comment: The automobile outshone the horse and buggy. :)

Answer (score 15):

I think "Replaced" can be used

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/replace?q=replaced)

> to take the place of something or put in the place of something or someone else:
>   We replaced our old air conditioners.
>   The ailing actress was replaced by her understudy.

In your example it would be

> The automobile **replaced** the horse and buggy.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most natural way to say it, particularly with the example given in the question.

Answer (score 12):

**Obviate**

*From the [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obviate)*

> 1. Remove (a need or difficulty) ‘the presence of roller blinds obviated the need for curtains’
>
>    1.1 Avoid or prevent (something undesirable)
>    ‘a parachute can be used to obviate disaster’

"The automobile obviated (removed the need for) the horse-and-buggy."

Comment: I prefer this word because it makes me feel smart every time I use it, obviating the need for a fancy degree from an exclusive university.

Comment: I was looking for this word! Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antiquate):

### antiquate, verb

> an·​ti·​quate | ˈan-tə-ˌkwāt
>
> transitive verb
>   : to make old or obsolete

Answer (score 4):

**Obsolesce**

transitive verb
: to make obsolescent

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolesce)

Comment: Obsolescent means "becoming obsolete", as in the process is still happening, which is slightly different from being obsolete already. A newer model of a phone or laptop may obsolesce older models the first day it's available (i.e. older models are now obsolescent), but doesn't immediately make them obsolete. It's still an applicable word, though, as there's not really a clear distinction between something that's *becoming* obsolete and something that *is* obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

Your most readily understood answer is going to be simply **made obsolete**. Here is why looking for something else can lead to problems:

Attempting to capture a precise meaning in a single word without context will often lead to ambiguities. While you provide context in one example, it doesn't necessarily apply in similarly worded examples.

To illustrate this, let's start with your context:

> The automobile made the horse and buggy obsolete.

I'll show some counterexamples further on that would make you question the value of these choices. But using some of the most up-voted suggestions, you can ask yourself: are these statements necessarily going to mean the same?

> The automobile *superseded* the horse and buggy.
>
> The automobile *supplanted* the horse and buggy.
>
> The automobile *deprecated* the horse and buggy.
>
> The automobile *displaced* the horse and buggy.
>
> The automobile *eclipsed* the horse and buggy.

For each of these words, there are multiple definitions. They are not all consistent with "make obsolete":

> supersede: to succeed to the position, function, office, etc., of
>
> supplant:  to take the place or move into the position of
>
> deprecate: to express disapproval of; deplore.
>
> displace:  to move from the usual or correct location
>
> eclipse:   to surpass; outshine

In choosing "the best words", you are still left with the job of ensuring that what the listener hears is the same as what you say.

If you changed the context, do these highlighted words mean "made obsolete"?

Here are the counterexamples:

> In the national park, federal law supersedes state law.
>
> This year, imported cars are expected to supplant domestically produced vehicles.
>
> The scientists were mocked in a move to deprecate the oil industry.
>
> The war displaced millions of people.
>
> When Ryun eclipsed the four minute mile, it became a realistic goal for many to strive for.

It should be obvious that none of these statements conveys the notion of *made obsolete*.

Words with multiple meanings have their place, and they only convey their intended meaning with the right context. None of the examples above about the automobile will necessarily be understood to mean "made obsolete" except to the person who already knows that simple fact.

Comment: "obsoleted" is a word, and I think is unambiguous.  But good examples and points about other proposed synonyms.

Comment: Words have more than one sense, which is why we want people who ask single-word-requests to give an example sentence. None of those words can replace *make obsolete* in the sentence *the automobile made the blacksmith obsolete,* but that's beside the point; we're looking for a word that works in the OP's (and similar) examples. I'm not really happy with any of the suggestions, either, but your answer does a terrible job of explaining why they're all no good.

Answer (score 3):

***Make redundant***, perhaps.

[*Redundant*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/redundant) - superfluous, excessive; surplus; unnecessary (OED).

Answer (score 3):

> What word means to make something obsolete?

I would use the verb 'outdate'. Although the adjective 'outdated' is more famous than the verb counterpart, the verb is in use on both sides of the pond.

According to [this Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outdate):

> Make out of date or obsolete.
>
> ‘new technology is outdating current privacy laws’

According to [Webster-Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outdate):

> : to make out of date : make obsolete
>
> the development of new machinery has outdated many plants

Answer (score 1):

Outmoded?

As in: "Pagers are every rarely used these days".

Comment: Hi 'The BFG', welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *outmoded* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would stay with your root, expanded to 'obsolescence', and use other verbs to set it up such as:

The automobile 'ushered in', or 'drove', or 'bulldozed in', or 'steamrolled in', or 'forced', or 'engineered' the obsolescence of the horse and buggy.

Since we're talking automobiles, I like 'drove'. :)

Comment: It would improve things if you included a couple of sample sentences to show what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

**Extinguish**

For an edgy substitute, where "killed" is too strong, you might consider something along the lines of **extinguished**.

Extinguish means to put an end to or bring to an end; wipe out of existence; annihilate. It is derived from the same Latin as the word **extinct**, and in your example with the horse and buggy, the automobile is the thing that brought (or drove, if you are pun-friendly) the horse and buggy to near extinction.

So the phrase

> The automobile extinguished the horse and buggy business.

is strong and empathic about the effect the auto had on the horse and buggy.

*(Note: consistent with Stack Exchange guidelines, I wish to keep this answer separate from my previous answer, as it is entirely distinct from that answer, and should stand on its own.)*

Answer (score 0):

The automobile renders the horse and buggy obsolete is a clear and complete sentence. Why does one need to make a verb out of an adjective?

Comment: It's called verbing a whatever. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/is-it-possible-to-verb-anything-other-than-a-noun

Comment: I love verbing words :^) Seriously, the statment *The automobile XXX the horse and buggy* is more concise and direct: *The automobile displaced the horse and buggy.*

Answer (score -2):

supplanted, succeeded, undermined, unseated, usurped, ejected, ousted

Comment: Please explain **how** each of these suggestions is useful.

Comment: On EL&U we're looking for answers that are *authoritative, detailed, and explain why they're correct*; how is a list of seven synonyms (some of which have already been proposed by others), with no explanation, any better than a bare link to a [thesaurus entry](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/supersede)?